# Как сопоставить числовое значение в regex?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Никак не могу сделать, чтоб минимальная цена была меньше 10, а максимальная не меньше 10
Обычные варианты перебирают только от 0 до 10, или по двум значениям от 0 до 10(или как угодно)

Comment: Во-первых, максимально не понятно, что вы написали. Минимальная цена меньше 10, а максимальная не меньше 10. ЧТО? Это вообще как? И причем тут regex? Regex используется для поиска определенных подстрок в строках, а не как универсальный фильтр значений, который вам еще и выборку сделает. Поэтому всю эту логику вы должны делать программно.

Comment: @NarasuOo
Таков последний, непонятный, пункт задания и задание само по себе не очень ясное.
Мне нужно из файла выбрать все строки, в которых минимальная цена была меньше 10, а максимальная не меньше 10

Comment: А какой формат цены - целые числа. или с центами/копейками? И какой формат строки, в смысле, сколько раз в ней содержатся цены?   Можно по идее искать минимальную цену как одноразрядное число, а максимальную - как двух- и более разрядное.  Было бы желательно увидеть какие-нибудь тестовые данные и ожидаемые результаты.

Comment: Число от 1 до 9 - [`^[1-9]$`](https://regex101.com/r/2JXJuW/3), число от 10 и выше - [`^[1-9][0-9]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/2JXJuW/1)

Comment: @AlexRudenko Вот пример строки из файла:
100890!ACE TENNIS NET              !58    !46.4  !01-JAN-89
!58 - макс. цена
!46.4 - мин. цена

Comment: @iBullRay И тогда получается, что минимальная цена не определена вообще (она больше 10) и строка должна быть отброшена
Если известно, что указывается две цены, то задача проще, если цен - некоторое множество, то сложнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для указанного формата строки (`!MIN!MAX!` или `!MAX!MIN!`) с разделителями `!` получилось [такое выражение](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydv3xj6r):

```
.*(!\s*((\d\d(\.\d{1,2})?)\s*!\s*(\d(\.\d{1,2})?|\.\d{1,2})|(\d(\.\d{1,2})?|\.\d{1,2})\s*!\s*(\d\d(\.\d{1,2})?))\s*!).*
```

Здесь проверяются как целые числа, так и с дробной частью до двух знаков, максимальные числа определяются не больше 100.